# The field of rational polynomials?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

So I was looking across the definition for irreducible polynomials on [Wolfram Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IrreduciblePolynomial.html) when I came across this:

> For example, in the field of rational polynomials $\mathbb{Q}[x]$...

But I feel that there's no such field? Polynomials can't form a field, can they? I just want to make sure.

Comment: You are absolutely right. This is not the first time I see huge mistakes on Wolfram Mathworld. E.g. "all satellite knots are prime"...

Comment: @ArnaudMortier Until now I have trusted it as a credible source when my textbook isn't at hand... XD

Comment: To be fair, is it possible this was short for "in the field of study of rational polynomials..."?

Comment: @CMonsour I don’t think so, the field on that page is hyperlinked to the field as a mathematical concept

Comment: Then that's quite bad!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This just terminology, but $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ denotes the ring of all polynomials with coefficients in the rational numbers.

This has a fraction field, consisting of all quotients of such functions, which is what I assume the quote refers to. This is the field of elements of the form $\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}$, where $p$ and $q$ are rational polynomials as above. This is sometimes denoted by $\mathbb{Q}(x)$. We use square brackets to enlarge something as a ring, i.e. admitting sums and powers of the thing, and we use parentheses to extend something as a field. These are of course very different in general.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't know the terminology before.

Comment: To add to the confusion, there exist notations $\mathbb{Q}[[x]]$ and $\mathbb{Q}((x))$ (e.g. see page 10 of [this handout](http://ericmoorhouse.org/handouts/intro_to_fields.pdf)) in addition to $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ and $\mathbb{Q}(x)$.